# Curtain.js getting "stuck"

Tags: jquery-plugins, cross-browser, html

i am trying to use the Curtain.js plugin on a website i am making for a friend.
The site is still not ready, there are some "pages" missing, but today i noticed that there is something wrong.

When i preview the website on Safari (5.7.1) the website gets "stuck" between two of the pages. it never goes down to the third page...
I also notice that during the "scrolling" from the first to the second, something strange happens to the scrollbar!

When i preview the website on Chrome it works fine.

Do you see this problem also? in other browsers?
Any ideas what is happening here and how to fix it?

I don't have a clue where the problem is, so i don't know what code to post, but here is the link for a "test page" of the website:
http://popo.webatu.com/hottalent_test/TalentShow.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i think i found it!
Maybe other people have the same problem, so i'll post here what the problem is.

in my contact form, i had this:

```
<label><span class="formQuestion">Name:</span>
  <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</label>
```

i tried many things, and i noticed that when i remove the "AUTOFOCUS" from that input things seem to work fine.

so now my code looks like:

```
<label><span class="formQuestion">Name:</span>
  <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
</label>
```

Any ideas why this is so?

Hope maybe some day this is helpful to someone else!   ;)